# Binary char array into stringstream and pop from the buffer

Tags: c++

I have 20byte binary char array. I want to divide into 3 parts: 4byte, 8byte, 8byte. I implemented it like the following. It works but seems I might be able to use buffer stream. I want to know how to use it.

**Now**

```
void main()
{
    // _data is 20byte binary char array. 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111001110001111111001110000010110000001011101101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

    // strA (4 byte)
    string strA;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        strA += bitset<8>(_data.c_str()[i]).to_string();
    }

    cout << strA << endl; // 00000000000000000000000000000000

    // strB (8 byte)
    string strB;
    for (std::size_t i = 4; i < 12; ++i) {
        strB += bitset<8>(_data.c_str()[i]).to_string();
    }

    cout << strB << endl; // 0000000000000111100111000111111100111000001011000000101110110100

    // strC (8 byte)
    string strC;
    for (std::size_t i = 12; i < 20; ++i) {
        strC += bitset<8>(_data.c_str()[i]).to_string();
    }

    cout << strC << endl; // 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
}
```

**Expectation**

I want to implement like this.

```
void main()
{
    stringstream ss = _data;
    strA = ss.pop(4);
    strB = ss.pop(8);
    strC = ss.pop(8);
}
```

---

Update 1

Thank you guys. I'm trying all of answers you gave me one by one. I'm newbie in c++ so it takes time to understand it. The following is Anders K's one.

```
struct S { char four[4]; char eight1[8]; char eight2[8]; }; 
struct S *p = reinterpret_cast<S*>(&_data); 
cout << p->four << endl; // => Output "(" I think I can find way to output
```

---

Update 2

It works using string::substr. Thanks Zakir.

```
int main()
{
    // I don't know how to change to string value in smart way.. 
    string str;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < _data.size(); ++i) {
        str += bitset<8>(_data.c_str()[i]).to_string();
    }

    cout << str << endl; // 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111001110001111111001110000010110000001011101101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

    std::string d = str; // Your binary stream goes here
    int lenA = (4*8);  // First  4 Bytes
    int lenB = (8*8);  // Second 8 Bytes
    int lenC = (8*8);  // Last   8 Bytes

    std::string strA = d.substr(0,    lenA);
    std::string strB = d.substr(lenA + 1, lenB - 1);
    std::string strC = d.substr(lenA + lenB + 1, lenC - 1);

    cout << strA << endl; // 00000000000000000000000000000000
    cout << strB << endl; // 000000000000111100111000111111100111000001011000000101110110100
    cout << strC << endl; // 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
}
```

---

Update 3

I got an error when I try Scheff's way. This is my fault and I think I can solve it. And I think I should reconsider about _data's type.

```
int main
{
    const char data = _data;
    const char *iter = data;
    string strA = pop(iter, 4);
    string strB = pop(iter, 8);
    string strC = pop(iter, 8);
    cout << "strA: '" << strA << "'" << endl;
    cout << "strB: '" << strB << "'" << endl;
    cout << "strC: '" << strC << "'" << endl;
}
```

Make Error Message

```
error: no viable conversion from 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to
  'const char'
const char data = _data;
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a `stringstream` and not a `string`?  And also `void main()` should be `int main()`

Comment: Wouldn't it be more easy to group them in a `struct` or `class`? Those parts must have some specific names so it'll be more easy to use that in grouping. If you use a `class`, you can wrap up internal details and expose a nice interface to access those three parts.

Comment: why not do something like `struct S { char four[4]; char eight1[8]; char eight2[8]; }; struct S *p = reinterpret_cast<S*>(&_data[0]); ` seems otherwise like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose you a very **simple** alternative using `string::substr`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string _data="00010001001000100011001101000100\
0101010101100110011101111000100010011001101010101011101111001100\
1101110111101110111111111101111010101101101111101110111100000000";

  int lenA = (4*8);  //First 4 Bytes
  int lenB = (8*8);  //Second 8 Bytes
  int lenC = (16*8); //Last 16 Bytes

  string strA = _data.substr(0,    lenA - 1);
  string strB = _data.substr(lenA, lenB - 1);
  string strC = _data.substr(lenB, lenC - 1);

  std::cout << "strA: " << strA <<  endl;
  std::cout << "strB: " << strB <<  endl;
  std::cout << "strC: " << strC <<  endl;


  return 0;
}
```

This is neat and simple but gets your job done!
Demo [here](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/DAYOKTAZQS)

Output:-

```
strA: 0001000100100010001100110100010
strB: 010101010110011001110111100010001001100110101010101110111100110
strC: 100110011010101010111011110011001101110111101110111111111101111010101101101111101110111100000000
```

Comment: Did you notice the intended bitwise output of data bytes?

Comment: Hey @Scheff: My input itself is the bitwise data stream as a string - have pdated demo

Comment: Well, but the OP was to provide data bytes which shall be piecewise converted to strings with the respecitve bits. (Please, note the `bitset<8>().to_string()` which is used.)

Comment: Hmm. I got your point. It depends how "20 bytes binary char array" is interpreted. Thus, either your or mine is what the OP actually intended to do. The questioner should accept one of these answers. Then, we will know.

Comment: Yup agreed !! (But I like your 2nd solution better - more I think of it...)

Comment: I accepted this answer since it is simple for me (c++ newbie). And I will consider to use struct or class to store metadata like length of byte following the advices in comments. Thank you Scheff, Zakir and all.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to make a new method for `std::stringstream`. (At least, I would not recommend this.)

Instead, I would suggest to make it a function. The usage would be similar.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string pop(istream &in, size_t n)
{
  string ret;
  while (n--) {
    unsigned char byte = (unsigned char)in.get();
    ret += bitset<8>(byte).to_string();
  }    
  return ret;
}

int main()
{
  string data(
    "\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99\xaa"
    "\xbb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff\xde\xad\xbe\xef\x00", 20);
  istringstream in; in.str(data);
  string strA = pop(in, 4);
  string strB = pop(in, 8);
  string strC = pop(in, 8);
  cout << "strA: '" << strA << "'" << endl;
  cout << "strB: '" << strB << "'" << endl;
  cout << "strC: '" << strC << "'" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
strA: '00010001001000100011001101000100'
strB: '0101010101100110011101111000100010011001101010101011101111001100'
strC: '1101110111101110111111111101111010101101101111101110111100000000'
```

Note:

1. Using a `std::istream` makes it applicable to any stream derived from `std::istream`.
2. There is no error handling in `pop()`. Thus, the returned result of `pop()` might be wrong if the passed stream isn't `good()` afterwards.

Btw. I agree with the comments that a `std::stream` might be "over-engineered". Thus, here the "light-weight" version:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string pop(const char *&iter, size_t n)
{
  string ret;
  while (n--) {
    ret += bitset<8>((unsigned char)*iter++).to_string();
  } 
  return ret;
}

int main()
{
  const char data[] =
    "\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99\xaa"
    "\xbb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff\xde\xad\xbe\xef\x00";
  const char *iter = data;
  string strA = pop(iter, 4);
  string strB = pop(iter, 8);
  string strC = pop(iter, 8);
  cout << "strA: '" << strA << "'" << endl;
  cout << "strB: '" << strB << "'" << endl;
  cout << "strC: '" << strC << "'" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is identical like above.

Note:

1. The usage of `char[]` and `char*` is much more sensitive for out-of-bound access. Thus, it has to be used carefully.
2. I'm not quite sure whether the `(unsigned char)` cast is necessary. As I have often seen "funny" effects concerning `char`, `int` and sign extension, I guess it cannot hurt. (I feel better with it.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm now trying to use your code in my environment.